# How to Correctly Remove All elements(including wxsizers and wxwindows) from inside a wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, sizer

Hi i am trying to remove all elements(including wxSizers and wxWindows) from inside a wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL) . The hierarchy structure I am using is shown in the screenshot below.

1. wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL) : this contains everything and i want to remove everything inside this sizer. Let's call this sizer the mainSizer.
2. wxPanel: Let's call this elementPanel
3. wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL): this contains the horizontal sizer in step 4
4. wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL): this contains both wxStaticText and the horizontal spacer
5. wxStaticText that holds the text I want to display
6. wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL): This is the horizontal spacer of fixed width.

Note that there are two more vertical spacers that are placed above and below the statictext to make the static text vertically centered but I have not shown them in the diagram.

I have exactly one mainSizer and many such elementPanels vertically placed, as the containing mainSizer is vertical.  Now I want to remove all the vertically placed elementPanels(and everything inside it) from the mainSizer. How can I achieve this? And does a wxsizer have an id associated with it? If not, how can i find this particular mainSizer from another part of the program so that i can remove everything inside of it. That is, I want to remove all the elementPanels(and everything inside) that I added in the mainSizer but do not delete the mainSizer itself.

I guess i can have the mainSizer inside a wxPanel and use its id to get to the mainSizer. But still the problem remains how can i delete every child(including sizer and wxWindow) from the mainSizer?

[image: mainSizer]

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#ade8de9a91bb5bf49c3a52e5262a5ffea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no command to remove or destroy the children of a sizer.
From the documentation of the deprecated function wxSizer::Remove(wxWindow* window)

> wxSizer::Remove(wxWindow* window); "Removes a child window from the sizer, but does not destroy it (because windows are owned by their parent window, not the sizer)."

So to destroy elements of a sizer you'd have to call DestroyChildren() from the parents of the panels. You could make a window solely for this purpose and have it's children be the elements you want in your box sizer.

```
parentWindowInsideBoxSizer->DestroyChildren();
```

You can also remove individual children.

```
parentWindowInsideBoxSizer->RemoveChild(child)
```

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#acee332ed4368d26e8bc3db5767c1240a

Comment: There seems to be a problem when usuing DestroyChildren(). When i use it to remove all the children from a list then the memory consumption is not reduced as is seen in the Task manager. In my case i have a list of 1000 items and they are taking up around 50 MB of memory. When i use DestroyChildren(), i can see that the destructor() is called on each of the child elements but still the memory that the program takes is not reduced . That is before calling DestroyChildren() the program is taking around 60 MB of memory and after i call DestroyChildren() it is taking the same amount of memory.

Comment: This may help you. https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=40265

Comment: I should answer instead of just a link in case someone else runs into this issue. You can try destroying the panel that is the parent of the windows you destroy and then recreating the panel when you need it. If that's not possible with your current configuration you may need to develop a workaround.

Comment: In my case when i use DestroyChildren() to destroy all the elements from the list i can see that the children are destroyed as seen on the screen but the problem is that, the "freed memory" is not given back to the OS. I think the elements are correctly destroyed but still the memory is not given back to the OS.